# CreateGlobalJavascriptObject issues

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, exception, awesomium

I trying to use CreateGlobalJavascriptObject in my app, but have issues. Code:

```
WebCore.Initialize(WebConfig.Default);
webControl.Source = new Uri("file:///res/login.html");
webControl.Update();
JSObject myGlobalObject = webControl.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("object");
```

Output: **System.AccessViolationException in Awesomium.Windows.Forms.dll.**

After that I trying just to put **webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("object");** in the default Awesomium WinForms sample project:

```
    public WebForm()
    {
        WebSession session = InitializeCoreAndSession();
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeView( WebCore.CreateWebView( this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height, session ) );
        webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("object");
    }
```

Output: **System.NullReferenceException in Awesomium.Core.dll.**

How I can resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very same question has been answered already on [answers.awesomium.com](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/6151/createglobaljavascriptobject-issues.html). I'll post the answer here as well so that it might help others:

You have to wait until the frame is loade. Use the IWebView.LoadingFrameComplete event:

```
webView.LoadingFrameComplete += OnLoadingFrameComplete;
```

And your event handler could look similar to this:

```
private void OnLoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
{
   JSObject myGlobalObject= webControl.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("myObject");
}
```